# Organizing similar class and instance methods within a class

Tags: matlab, class, oop, methods

I have a class, for which I have static methods that calculate something (example below in MATLAB, since that's what I'm using, although I think my question may be more general):

```
methods (Static)

    function out = f(x)
       out = x*2;
    end

end
```

Suppose I have instance methods where I want to do the same calculation (and hence use the aforementioned class method), but I also want to do something specific to the class, like updating a property or maybe passing in an instance property into the calculation. So like:

```
methods

    function out = f(this)
        out = ClassName.f(this.x);  % Use the class method, but pass in an instance variable
    end

    % OR

    function [this, out] = f(this,x)
        out = ClassName.f(x)*2;  % Use the class method with a provided input
        this.value = out;        % then assign value to an instance variable
    end

end
```

At least in MATLAB, I can't overload a class method with an instance method (I can [overload a built-in MATLAB method within my class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/overloading-functions-for-your-class.html), but that's not what I want here), so I'm not sure how to go about this in a proper OOP way. I want to keep the class method there in case someone wants to use the specific calculation on some data they collected outside the class, but I also want the instance method in case someone decides to use the class to collect data and then analyze the data with the built methods.

Comment: Seems like your static method should really be an independent function. It has nothing to do with the class, it shouldn’t be a member. That way you can overload it for your class, and it remains available for use with data outside the class.

Comment: I think you might be right! I think if I stored those calculation methods as a separate library that would be the way to go.

Comment: A class is not a library. Just put a function M-file next to your classdef M-file. There is also the concept of [namespace](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html).